# Segmentation Fault when calling NSRegularExpression:matchesInString

Tags: ios, objective-c, segmentation-fault, nsregularexpression

I have a crash in my (deployed) iOS-App while starting. It looks like it happens in some lib-functions and I'm not sure how this could be. The console output says

```
Oct 15 17:05:42 iPadMiniR MyApp[260] <Warning>: INFO: downloading package data 5 of 5...
Oct 15 17:05:42 iPadMiniR ReportCrash[261] <Error>: task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument)
Oct 15 17:05:42 iPadMiniR ReportCrash[261] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 260
Oct 15 17:05:42 iPadMiniR diagnosticd[150] <Error>: error evaluating process info - pid: 260, punique: 260
Oct 15 17:05:42 iPadMiniR ReportCrash[261] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process myApp[260]
```

so I analyzed the Crash Report:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000058
Triggered by Thread:  4
[...]
Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001946d3bd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                      0x0000000184ac884c -[NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult initWithRanges:count:regularExpression:] + 176
2   Foundation                      0x0000000184aaf2a4 -[NSRegularExpression(NSMatching) enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:] + 1340
3   Foundation                      0x0000000184ac8720 -[NSRegularExpression(NSMatching) matchesInString:options:range:] + 152
4   myApp                           [...]
```

I know what a Segfault is but I don't understand, why it can happen in a Library function. I already searched in Apple's developer documentation of [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRegularExpression/matchesInString:options:range:) (under `enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:` and `matchesInString:options:range:`) and googled for `NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult`, but I didn't find a thing that helps. In similar questions here on StackOverflow, the SIGSEGV occurs not in library functions but in the user's code.

My question is: How could a Segfault in this context occur? Doesn't the objective-C-Library-Functions check pointers? Or could it be that a pointer become dangled between the check and the usage (weak pointers, but I don't have any of them)?

I'm pretty new to iOS development, so thanks for any help :)

I use XCode 6.0.1 and iOS 8.0.2.

Comment: It's possible that the symbol table you were using to decode the crash report does not match the symbol table within the build; this would cause incorrect symbols to appear in your crash reports. Are you 100% sure that you used the correct one?

Comment: Try to add Exception breakpoint (In break point navigator - 7th tab) and run your code again. Because of that your app will stop on right place where exception is.